# How to type-annotate object returned by csv.writer?

Tags: python, csv, type-hinting

I want to apply type annotation to the returned object of [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer) in order to comply with a larger codebase. Unfortunately I can not figure out the fitting return type.

```
>>> import csv
>>> writer = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv', 'w'))
>>> type(writer)
<class '_csv.writer'>
```

If I try to use this classname:

```
>>> import _csv
>>> writer: _csv.writer = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv', 'w'))
```

I get the following mypy error:

```
Invalid type "_csv.writer"
```

Does someone know which type to use in this case. Of course I could use `typing.Any` but this nullify the sense of a type annotation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Often when things are acting weird it's a sign typeshed doesn't exactly map to runtime. If you look at _csv [in typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/e2fd852952ff807c60819f8840e8b23664cc7593/stdlib/_csv.pyi#L1) you will see the type is named `_writer`. So you should can the annotation to `_csv._writer`.

Comment: That leads to `error: Name 'csv._writer' is not defined`

Comment: You need to use `_csv._writer`

Comment: Indeed, typeshed was changed so `_writer` is no longer re-exported. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I learned about Typeshed which "contains external type annotations for the Python standard library and Python builtins, as well as third party packages as contributed by people external to those projects." Also "If using mypy you don't need to interact with the typeshed repo at all: a copy of standard library part of typeshed is bundled with mypy."

Comment: Why does mypy with typeshed not provide a stub for something so standard as the csv module?

Comment: @boardtc typeshed does provide csv stubs, I've fixed the link (its now permanent)

Comment: python 3.6.10 gives `AttributeError: module '_csv' has no attribute '_writer'`.

Comment: @DanielChin make it a string literal `import _csv` then  `f: '_csv._writer'`

Comment: In general, using things prefixed with `_` in Python is not a good idea, as [they are intended semantically to not be public features](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) and therefore cannot be relied upon consistently.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into problems with the typeshed defs and ended up using the following:

```py
class Writer(Protocol):
    def writerow(self, row: Iterable[Any]) -> Any:
        ...

    def writerows(self, rows: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> None:
        ...


Reader = Iterator[Any]
```

```py
writer: Writer = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv', 'w'))
reader: Reader = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is there is no way to directly access the type. Reading the [C source of the _csv module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_csv.c) will show that the types of `reader` and `writer` are not exposed. Even in [Pypy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/lib_pypy/_csv.py) where the _csv module is implemented in Python, doesn't expose the types.

Therefore, if you need to use it, you will need to use a work-around, by instantiating a temporary instance of the writer and getting it's type.

```
import csv
# We'll need a temporary file-like object, so use a tempfile
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

with TemporaryFile() as t:
    CSVReader = type(csv.reader(t))
    CSVWriter = type(csv.writer(t))

w: CSVWriter = csv.writer('path/to/data.csv')
```

If you want keep this logic separate, I would suggest creating the types in a separate module

```
from csv_types import CSVReader, CSVWriter
```

The other solution (which also involves writing your own module of types), is to follow the example of the [`typing`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/typing.py) module in it's definition of types for `io` and `re`.

Comment: The workaround works well on the Python console. However it will not work with a static type-checker like mypy. There will be an `InvalidType` error. I think this is because mypy does not actually execute the code. However thanks to your hint with the second solution. That one actually put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to write an abstract class that represents the type. This is also how it is done for some classes in the [typing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/typing.py) module. For the [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) function that is the following:

```
class _CSVWriter:

    @abstractmethod
    def writerow(self, row: List[str]) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def writerows(self, rows: List[List[str]]) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def dialect(self) -> csv.Dialect:
        pass
```

Now this class can be used in the type-annotation for the `writer` object. As the typename of the returned object is still `_csv.writer` you will still get a type error. To avoid that you need to cast it to a `_CSVWriter` object.

```
from typing import cast
writer: _CSVWriter = cast(_CSVWriter, csv.writer(open('test', 'w'))
```

That solution is a bit verbose but it does the job.

Comment: `_CSVWriter` should subclass `typing.Protocol`.  That way, you don't need the cast.

Comment: Nor would you need the `abstract...` decorators.

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented, but I was able to find it at `_csv.Writer` as of Python 3.10.

```py
>>> import csv
>>> from _csv import Writer
>>> 
>>> repr(_csv.Writer)
"<class '_csv.writer'>"
>>> 
>>> writer = csv.writer(file)
>>> isinstance(writer, Writer)
True
```

I would avoid using this in production software since, given the other comments, the symbol's name appears to have been changed over time.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the original class inherits from `Iterator` so I was able to do:

```
from typing import Iterator

with open(spec_file) as csv_file:
            spec_csv: Iterator = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

and then with `mypy` voila:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```